# For all subfolders in a Node.js project, use global custom entry point for require

Tags: node.js, require, entry-point

**Question**

Is it possible to configure a global, custom entry point to be used by `require` for all subfolders in a Node.js project?

**Rationale**

When working in Node.js, I like having my `index.js` file as the topmost file in each subfolder in my IDE.

However, depending on the IDE and the way it sorts files, this is not always possible (for example, VSCode has several sorting options available, and none of them can achieve this).

To achieve that, I prefix it with `_index.js`, **but then lose the built-in capability of `require` to recognize it as the default entry point.**

Although **this can be mitigated** by adding a `package.json` into **each** subfolder, with a `main` property directing to the entry point file - I'd like to know if there's a way to define a **"global"** custom entry point, be it in the topmost package.json or using some npm package which I'm not aware of.

**Example**

Let's say I have the following folders structure, and assume that our IDE sorts files alphabetically:

```
MyApp
├── app.js
├── package.json
├─┬ featureA
│ ├── func1.featureA.js
│ ├── func2.featureA.js
│ └── index.js
└─┬ featureB
  ├── func1.featureB.js
  ├── func2.featureB.js
  └── index.js
```

To keep `index.js` as the topmost file, we prefix it with an underscore, and use a `package.json` for each subfolder to define it as an entry point:

```
MyApp
├── app.js
├── package.json
├─┬ featureA
│ ├── _index.js
│ ├── func1.featureA.js
│ ├── func2.featureA.js
│ └── package.json
└─┬ featureB
  ├── _index.js
  ├── func1.featureB.js
  ├── func2.featureB.js
  └── package.json
```

The `package.json` for both `featureA` and `featureB` is identical:

```
{
  "main": "_index.js"
}
```

That `package.json` is necessary so that we can use `require` in the following way in `app.js`:

```
// app.js
const featureA = require('./featureA');
const featureB = require('./featureB');
```

But can these two `package.json` files be replaced with some "global" alternative?

Comment: Using `index.js` as the default entry point is one of Node.js original author's regrets. I don't think there's an easy way to change it globally. Unless you use a require hook or do some transpilation.